# download file from array improper output in laravel

Tags: php, csv, laravel

Trying to download file using laravel. Dont want to put file in public folder and bom and utf8 charset is necessary as i need to write japanese character.

the code is as below

```
  header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
  header('Content-type: text/csv');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Customers_Export.csv');
  echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
  $string = '21, 133, 3232';
  echo $string;
  exit();
```

But our output is like below we are getting two additional blank lines and japanese char is improper

```
**Output in csv**
```

> blank line
>
> blank line
>
> ï»¿21    133 3232

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: have you tried to use the [docs example in file download](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#file-downloads), if you wonder what `$header` should be, look  at [this api guide](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_download).

Comment: response()->download($pathToFile);                                                              I cant use any $pathToFile as it will be public

Comment: then, look a little bit to the early part of the page [the plain `response()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses). it'll looked like `return response("\xEF\xBB\xBF**\n**21, 133, 3232")->header('Content-Type', 'text/csv')->header('Content-Encoding', 'UTF-8')->header('Content-Disposition, 'attachment; filename: =Customers_Export.csv');` - the underlying [`->download()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php#L129) just looked like this. anyway $pathToFile it can be a path to your storage.

Comment: $response()->download() provide a file from non-pubic directories, for example storage/files.

Comment: "$pathToFile it can be a path to your storage."   how can i do that. create with just this line in temp location/any place not public and then download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sooo a big surprise comes out here..

I have found out the reason of blank lines..and that was empty line before php tag in route files!!!

amazingly i removed the blank lines there and there is no blank line in my csv file also...

Comment: Absurd, but actually fixed my blank lines and encoding issues...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `response()->download()` to download a file from any location.

Here's how I do it:

```
$headers = array
(
    'Content-Encoding: UTF-8',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
);
return response()->download($path, $file_name, $headers);
```

For example, my app is located in `/var/www/appname` and my files in `/storage/appname`, so the files aren't public.

Comment: But it is still adding two blank line in at the starting of the csv :(

Comment: I just need the blank lines removed.. Need help :(

Comment: Doesn't work when opening the file. I still can't see the unicode characters.